# How do you make the text flow like the new my space article pages?

Tags: css, overflow, multiple-columns, myspace

I'm trying to create a multi-column layout that wraps the text vertically as well as horizontally like this: https://new.myspace.com/discover/trending/2013/01/23/jeremy-allen-white-cant-get-away-from-sex

I can't seem to find any article that can help me.

This is what I have in my stylesheet, but the text in each column wraps around before reaching the bottom of the browser.

Here is what it currently looks like:
http://jsfiddle.net/koryeast/ztfED/

```
@media (min-width:800px)
{
    div
    {
        -webkit-column-fill: auto;
        -webkit-column-width: 300px;
        -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    }
}
```

But as you can see the text in each column wraps around before reaching the bottom of the browser.

How can I make the text overflow to the next column only when it reaches the bottom of the browser?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please post a bit more code.  Put a small snippet up at http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tutorial to do this. Go to http://kmsm.ca/2010/an-almost-complete-guide-to-css3-multi-column-layouts/ . This explains it all. Also, a similar question with a working version can be found here [re-arange default column (-webkit-column, -moz-column) order on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817427/re-arange-default-column-webkit-column-moz-column-order-on-a-page). Hope this helps.